# DocuSign - Update Envelope - Add or Update Custom Text Field

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

I'm trying to update an envelope with the status sent. I want to either add a new custom text field or update an existing one.

I have tried via API explorer and via the DocuSign.eSign NuGet package and the result is always the same: INVALID_CUSTOM_FIELD_ID. The response is the same regardless of whether I provide a field ID or not. I have tried multiple combinations to either update an existing field or add a new field without success.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I can update the Status in the same request. However, the custom text field update/add still fails.

Request (existing field):

```
{
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": "1",
        "name": "CreatedByEmail",
        "required": "true",
        "show": "true",
        "value": "dummy@dummy.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "envelopeId": "...",
  "textCustomFieldUpdateResults": [
    {
      "fieldId": "1",
      "name": "CreatedByEmail",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "INVALID_CUSTOM_FIELD_ID",
        "message": "Value cannot be null."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what endpoint do you use? the PUT envelope endpoint?

Comment: Are you using https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopecustomfields/update/ this ?

Comment: Yes, I use PUT and I use I use /envelopes/update/ or in other words the explorer/package do that. I do not explicitly specify either. I have tried with and without advanced_update set: When set to true, allows the caller to update recipients, tabs, custom fields, notification, email settings and other envelope attributes.

Comment: I can add a custom field using the envelopes/envelope/customfields/update. However, I would like to do it using the envelops/update as I wan to create the fields as part of the void process.

Comment: you cannot do this with the envelopes/update, you should be able to do that with the envelopes/envelope/customfields/update which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: Also, if an envelope is voided, what's the need to add custom fields? it seems very odd. But you would have to do this with two different API calls.

Comment: It makes sense to our business process. Where is the documentation for your statement? The documentation states that you can use envelope/update to update custom fields when setting the advanced_update.

Comment: Let me check on that